# Overloading '<<' so it is usable with more than one object

Tags: c++

I'm starting to get a grasp of operator overloading but I've hit a wall. I cant figure out how I would make '<<' work the way it is redefined to work with more than one type of object from my class. I have to use one of my class constructors to initialize two separate matrices so I need to make two different objects like so: matrix a(sizeIn, rangeIn), b(sizeIn, rangeIn); but as you can see below my '<<' overloading function only uses one class parameter. Can anyone help me out?

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const matrix & a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size; i++)

    {
        cout << '|';
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size; j++)
            {
            os << setw(4) << a.array[i][j] << " ";
            }
        os << setw(2) << '|' << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Post the code that calls this operator.

Comment: What do you mean by "work with more than one type of object" of your class?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing `std::cout << a << b << std::endl;` ?

Comment: It *is* usable with more than one object. `cout << a << b << endl;` should work fine. Remove the `endl` from the operator though, the operator should just print the `matrix` and not enforce formatting such as e.g. adding `'\n'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work with more than one object because the `<<` overload returns a reference to the stream. `<<` is evaluated<sup>1</sup> left to right, so if you do:

```
stream << a << b << c;
```

it is equivalent to:

```
((stream << a) << b) << c;
```

now, since your `(stream << a)` function returns an `ostream&`, we could think of this as:

```
((stream) << b) << c;
```

and so on :)

<sub>1: technically, it 'associates' left to right, leading to left-to-right evaluation.</sub>

Comment: ah, excellent, I only had cout << a << endl. I thought, i needed to specify whether it would be a or b in the overloading function.Thanks!